# What are the programming languages for uiq3 software development?

Tags: mobile, symbian, uiq3

I know that UIQ3 production is stopped. Yet, i still own a UIQ3 phone. I'd like to create a simple internet browser for my own use.

What are the programming languages for uiq3 software development?

So far i've found that NSbasic is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find a place to download the UIQ3 SDK, Symbian C++ can be used.  Alternatively you could write a Java Midlet.

Comment: Can we create UIQ3 apps using Visual Basic 6 ??

Comment: No I don't believe that is possible. NS Basic which you've already mentioned is the only form of Basic that I know of that is usable.